# free-jqGrid remove ui sliding when click on header titlebar close button

Tags: user-interface, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I didn't find how to cancel ui sliding animation when clickin on header titlebar close button.
Plz can find some time to drive me to do it ?
Many thanks for your kindly help.
JiheL

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you mean. You can use `hidegrid: false` to remove the button, which can be used by users to hide/minimize the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems that I have not been enough specific in my request. My pb is about animation when I click on hide button, the grid slides down or up and I would like no animation. I hope I will be fine in my explanation. Thanks again. have a nice day. JiheL

Answer (score 0):

There are no special option to customize the animation effects on click on "Hiding" button because the feature is not the main feature of jqGrid. jqGrid have already a lot of options, callbacks and events. A look at the file [free-jqgrid.d.ts](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.0/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts) shows that it has more 2000 rows. One can't introduce more options for every small elements of the grid.

If animation effects make some problem I'd recommend you **to remove** the button by usage the option `hidegrid: false`.